# Error de conexión con GitHub

Tags: java, git, spring-boot, github, spring-tool-suite

Desde hace unos días he estado teniendo problemas con la conexión a la plataforma GitHub en un proyecto personal desde Spring Boot, indica el siguiente error:

```
Transport Error: Cannot get remote repository refs.
https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git: git-upload-pack not permitted on 'https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git/'
```

¿Alguien tendrá solución al problema? Desde consola y otras herramientas trabaja bien, saben si hubo algún cambio de configuración?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hubo un cambio en gitHub en agosto 13, 2021, 09:00 PST, y ya no permiten usar usuario y contraseña para varias operaciones. Debe usarse autenticación token-based para esas operaciones.

[Notificación de GitHub](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-12-git-password-authentication-is-shutting-down/)

Lo que procede hacerse lo informan en [el blog](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/#what-you-need-to-do-today), que básicamente es tener un [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)

Comment: Es correcto, muchas gracias por la información